# Does socket in SWI-Prolog have a big bug?

Tags: sockets, stream, swi-prolog

I wrote a server with Python, and a client with SWI-Prolog.
The client can send message to the server, but can not receive
message sent from server.

The source of two programs are at below.

```
1). The server
```

import socket

if "**main**" == **name**:

```
try:

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(('localhost',8888))
    sock.listen(5)
except:
    print("init socket err!")

while True:
    print('\n listren for client...')
    conn,addr = sock.accept()
    print('get client')
    print(addr)

    conn.settimeout(5)
    szBuf = conn.recv(1024)
    print(byt)

    if '0' == szBuf:
        conn.send(b'exit')
    else:
        conn.send(b'welcome client!')

    conn.close()
    print('end of the service')

2). The client 

:- use_module(library(socket)).

create_client :-
    setup_call_catcher_cleanup(
        tcp_socket(Socket),
        tcp_connect(Socket, localhost:8888),
        exception(_),
        tcp_close_socket(Socket)
    ),
    setup_call_cleanup(
        tcp_open_socket(Socket, In, Out),
        chat_to_server(In, Out),
        close_connection(In, Out)
    ).

close_connection(In, Out) :-
    close(In, [force(true)]),
    close(Out, [force(true)]).

chat_to_server(In, Out) :-
    write(Out,'....... 12345 .........'),
    read(In,Term),
    nl,write(Term),nl.
```

When the client run, the server soon exit and show the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\PyQt4\learn\sockets\server2.py", line 24, in <module>
      szBuf = conn.recv(1024)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

The server then stop untill restart the server.

But if delete the predicate, read(In,Term), 
both the client and the server will run normally.

The new clause is as below:

```
chat_to_server(In, Out) :-
    write(Out,'....... 12345 .........')
```

Why the problem occurred, and how to correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting a 5 millisecond timeout, which is absurdly short, so the read times out. You probably meant 5 seconds, which is an argument value of 5000.